# EER Diagrams, different symbols?

Tags: database, database-design, diagram, eer-model

Sometimes when I'm working with EER diagrams I see different symbols,
for example, 'd', 'o', 'u' and so on. 
[Like the 'd' here](http://cisnet.baruch.cuny.edu/holowczak/classes/9440/entityrelationship/er6_elmasri.gif)

What do they mean and what are they used for? And how many variants do it exists?

Answer (score 6):

1.**d** means "**disjoint**"- what it tells is the subclasses must have disjoint sets of entities.

[image]

2.**o** means "**overlap**"The subclasses may have overlapping sets of entities.
[image]

3. **U** symbol indicates the Subtype is a subset of the Supertype.
   [image]

4.Place **o** or **d** in specialization circle to indicate constraint.

Comment: the link you gave is only for authorized access